# COUNT(*) queries in Hive behaving differently when ran with UNION ALL

Tags: hive, hiveql, union-all

I ran two queries to get count of records for two different dates from a Hive managed table partitioned on process date field.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM prd_fct.mktng WHERE process_dt='2018-01-01' --returned 2 million
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM prd_fct.mktng WHERE process_dt='2018-01-02' --returned 3 million
```

But if I ran the below query with a `UNION ALL` clause, the counts returned are different from that of above mentioned individual queries.

```
SELECT '2018-01-01', COUNT(1) FROM prd_fct.mktng WHERE process_dt='2018-01-01' 
UNION ALL
SELECT '2018-01-02', COUNT(1) FROM prd_fct.mktng WHERE process_dt='2018-01-02'
```

What can be the root cause for this difference?

Answer (score 0):

One of our teammate helped us to identify the issue.
When we run a single count(*) query,the query is not physically executed on table rather count will be taken from statistics.
One of the remedy is to collect the stats on table agian,then the count(*) on single table will reflect actual count

Regards,
Anoop

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar issue with `count(*)` returning incorrect count. I added the below to my code and the counts are consistent now.

For non-partitioned table use:

```
ANALYZE TABLE your_table_name COMPUTE STATISTICS
```

For partitioned table, analyze the recently added partition by specifying the partition value:

```
ANALYZE TABLE your_table_name 
PARTITION(your_partition_name=your_partition_value) 
COMPUTE STATISTICS;
```